# can i get a value from the main table inside a function of a relation table? laravel with

Tags: laravel, sql-order-by, relationship

```
        $main->with(['relation' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderByRaw("main.colunm + relation.colunm DESC");
        }]);
```

something like this, where I would like to order by a value from the main table with one from the relation table

Comment: Nope. `->with()` doesn't perform any kind of join logic, so `main.column` is currently unknown. If you want to perform that `orderByRaw()`, you'll need to include some kind of `->join()` within that `->with()` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add join in order to get parent table columns.

```
$main->with(['relation' => function ($query) {
    $query->join('main', 'main.pk', '=', 'relation.fk')->orderByRaw("main.colunm + relation.colunm DESC");
}]);
```

It's also better to add aliases for table names so they don't conflict with relation columns.

Hopefully, This will work.